# How can I transpose a matrix in Groovy?

Tags: arrays, groovy, matrix, transpose

I need transpose an array from rows into cols and cols into rows

```
def mtrx = [
   [1,2,3],
   [4,5,6]
]
//mtrx.anyMethod()
//expected result
//[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

Do you know a direct method from it?

I don't know a Groovy method that transposes this case; if you know another way to transpose please tell me it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Groovy lists have a [`transpose()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.html#transpose(java.util.List)) method:

```
def transposed = mtrx.transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit of overkill for what you need, but the [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/index.html) library includes a comprehensive linear algebra module.  The [user's guide](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/linear.html) for the linear algebra module includes a simple matrix multiplication example.  You can include this module in your Grails project by adding:

```
runtime ('org.apache.commons','commons-math','2.2')
```

to your BuildConfig.groovy file.